# Detect cancel events of FileBrowse in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am trying to build a user interface using PySimpleGui. Below is a minimal example of a file browser button. If you click on the button, it opens an Open file dialog.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

file_browse_button = sg.FileBrowse(enable_events=True)
layout = [[file_browse_button]]
window = sg.Window('My window', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, '##', values)
    if event is None or event == 'Cancel':
        break
window.close()
```

When selecting a file, this produces (for example):

```
Browse ## {'Browse': '/path/to/file.txt'}
```

The problem is that if the user selects "Cancel" or just the previously selected file in the browser window, it will still produce the same event, not changing the value. Is there a way to differentiate the two cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that the FileBrowse button best operates with its target parameter.  That's how I use it anyway.  The target parameter is the key for another PySimpleGUI element in the window where the button will store its value when the user clicks "ok".  If the user clicks "Cancel" in the FileBrowse button, any selected value will not be inserted into the target.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


file_browse_button = sg.FileBrowse(target='filebrowse_field')
filebrowse_field = sg.Input(key='filebrowse_field')
ok_cancel = [ [sg.Button('OK'), sg.Button('Cancel')]]

layout = [[filebrowse_field, file_browse_button],
          ok_cancel]
window = sg.Window('My window', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, '##', values)
    if event is None or event == 'Cancel':
        break
window.close()
```

Note also that I don't have the enable-events option set for the FileBrowse element.  I believe the intention is that your window has in it ok, cancel button to manage those events explicitly.